# With my JQuery UI Datepicker, why does the icon appear on a separate line?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/1pm0vsf3/1/

I'm using a standard option, namely `buttonImage`:

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

but my calendar icon appears on a new line:

[image]

How do I get my calendar icon to appear on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.col-10::after {
  clear: both;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
}
input.key-event-datepicker {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

This adds floating to your input thus telling the button it can float next to your input. The after element on the col-10 clears the float so it won't affect the height of the parent container.
You should maybe still use a more unique identifier for your col-10 as this will add the float-clear to all your col-10 now.
Updated JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/obmajt1w/